# Map Reduce node coordination and MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, mpi, distributed-computing

Why Map Reduce is not good for applications requires node coordination? 
Also, when it is better than MPI for large scale distributed applications

Comment: Have you looked around for answers to questions on MPI vs MapReduce? There are lots of these already. Your question is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: I did looked around but I did not find something related to why Map Reduce is not good for node coordination.

Comment: What does node coordination mean exactly? Communication, synchronization,...?

Comment: it means data exchange and synchronization

Comment: That's not helpful. What specific application patterns matter to you?